# How do you change the macOS SDK associated with the swift compiler

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, metal

I have Xcode 7.3 installed, and the swiftc command line compiler declares that is is version 2.2, yet it is configured to target the macos10.9 sdk:

```
> swiftc -v
Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

FWIW I am running OS X 10.11.6. Compiling Metal API code using this swiftc in this configuration results in errors such as:

```
src/Application.swift:76:29: error: 'MTLBuffer' is only available on OS X 10.11 or newer
var _mtlPositionBuffer : MTLBuffer?
```

And finally, to address this, I've compiled with the flag:

```
-sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
```

to no avail.  How do you change the sdk/platform target for the swiftc command line compiler?

Comment: what device are you running your code on? only mobile devices with an A7 cpu or newer, and Macs that are 2012 or newer, are supported. Xcode simulators cannot run Metal code.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at what Xcode does when compiling swift code, it uses the following CLI flag, which seems to address the problem here nicely:

```
-target x86_64-apple-macosx10.11
```